# Create Array and fill with index plus one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create an Array using `new Array()` and filling with index + 1 but somehow, though array is creating successfully but values are not filling correctly.

**Code -**

```js
var aa = (new Array(4)).map((x, index) => {
    return index + 1;
});

console.log(aa);
```

Output - `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Expected - `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Thank you @adiga. I *knew* it would be there, just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`map` only visits entries that actually exist, it skips gaps in sparse arrays.

There are various ways to do this:

1. You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and its mapping callback:

   ```js
   const as = Array.from(Array(4), (_, index) => index + 1);

   console.log(as);
   ```
2. You can use a simple `for` loop:

   ```js
   const as = [];
   for (let index = 1; index <= 4; ++index) {
       as.push(index);
   }

   console.log(as);
   ```
3. You can use [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype/fill) and then `map`:

   ```js
   const as = Array(4).fill().map((_, index) => index + 1);

   console.log(as);
   ```
4. A variant of `fill`+`map`, you can use spread as [Igor shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62757553/157247).

Comment: Answer reflex. Sigh. I'm sure there's a dup;etarget. Marked CW and off to find it...

Comment: Why map over something you don't have to `Array(size + 1).fill().unshift()` or whatever other method you may prefer splice, slice, etc.

Comment: @MarceDev - That fills the array with `undefined`. The OP wants to fill it with the index + 1.

Answer (score 4):

```
[...Array(4)].map((v, i) => i + 1)
```

Comment: maybe a bit simpler:
new Array(4).fill(null).map((v, i) => i++)